# What can I put in the extend Exception class?

Tags: php, error-handling, try-catch

What can I put in the `extend Exception` class and how it can be used? As you can see I've included errors handing in the `catch` block.

For example:

```
class Manager {

    private $socket = null;

    private $config = array();

    public function connect($host = null, $port = null) {

        if ($host == null || $port == null) {
            throw new PortHostNotGivenException('Host or Port is missing');
        }

        $this->socket = fsockopen($host,$post);

    }
}


class PortHostNotGivenException extends Exception {
    // What to put here??
 }
```

Testing:

```
$ast = new Manager();

    try {
      $ast->connect();
    } catch (PortHostNotGivenException $e) {
       // Log Error to File
       // Log Error to Linux Console
       echo $e . '/r/n';
       exit();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can catch multiple distinct exceptions and treat them differently e.g.

```
try {
    $this->db->save();
} catch (ConnectionException $e) {
    if ($this->db->reconnect()) {
        // try again
    } else {
        throw new CannotReconnectException();
    }
} catch (ValidationException $e) {
    // display validation error messages
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // save failed with a general or unexpected error
}
```

You can also silently handle expected errors whilst not interfering with unexpected errors:

```
try {
  ...
} catch (VendorApiException $e) {
    return false;
}
```

In the above example if a `VendorApiException` is thrown - the code will just return false. If any other exception is thrown - it will not be captured by this `catch` block, and instead bubble up. If there is no higher try/catch block it would be handled by the process [exception handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php).

### The body of user-defined exceptions

> // What to put here??

Anything or nothing  - if you've no reason to override any of an [exceptions properties](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.extending.php) - don't put anything in it. Typically you may define a `code` and `message`, and possibly override the constructor if you're passing a `$message` that isn't a string.

Comment: I think I will be  repeating same code in every `catch` for example: Log Error to File,  Log Error to Linux Console, etc.  What the best way for DRY method.

Comment: @I'll-Be-Back If all you're doing is logging the exceptions, don't catch them. Rather, let them bubble up to your top level exception handler (which you can set using `set_exception_handler`) and log it there. IMO, exceptions should only be caught if they're recoverable. If not, your application should gracefully stop (with a nice warning page), or you risk larger issues

Comment: @ColinMorelli PHP script will be running in the background process on Linux - so I am looking for good solution to deal with that kind of error handling.

Comment: @I'll-Be-Back Again, as AD7 and I mentioned, just use a global exception handler unless you can recover.

Comment: @I'll-Be-Back long running processes and php don't go together that well. Write your code to handle what you know it can handle - and run/manage your daemon process with e.g. [supervisor](http://supervisord.org/) so that it will restart the process if (when) it dies. If you're using a db anticipate and account for connection timeouts =)

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to put anything there. The purpose of extending and Exception is mainly to "filter" waht Exception you are catching.

For example you have a CustomConfigNotFoundException and a DatabaseException where you can say meh i dont need the custom config because i can use the default for the time being but without database  you are screwed... so you can use catch(CustomConfigNotFoundException e) to load the default config and just let the DatabaseException stop you program / script / page whatever you use ur exception.